# Freemarker page can't include css files

Tags: spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, freemarker, spring-3

I am using Spring 3 ,java based configuration, with BootStrap.

I have downloaded the bootstrap and put the css and js  under resources directory.

The issue that I cann't use these .css from within the freemarker page.
Howeve that I imported them.

Tomcat log says :

> "WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
>   [/springway/resources/css/bootstrap-responsive.css] in
>   DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'"

Directory :

```
> -SpringWay
>       -src
>            - main
>                   -webapp
>                           -resources
                            -WEB-INF
                                 -welcome.ftl
                                 -springway.ftl
```

welcome.ftl:

```
[#ftl /]
[#include "springway.ftl" /]


<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li>
    <a href="[@spring.url '/test'/]">Test</a> <span class="divider">/</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Library</a> <span class="divider">/</span>
  </li>
  <li class="active">Data</li>
</ul>
```

springway.ftl:

```
[#ftl/]
[#import "spring.ftl" as spring /]

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <title>

    </title>

   <link href="[@spring.url '/resources/css/bootstrap-responsive.css'/]" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <link href="[@spring.url '/resources/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css'/]" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <link href="[@spring.url '/resources/css/bootstrap.css'/]" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <link href="[@spring.url '/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css'/]" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

    <script src="[@spring.url '/resources/js/bootstrap.js'/]" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="[@spring.url '/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js'/]" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>

<body ></body>
</html>
```

WebAppConfig:

```
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
```

Comment: The question is phrased strangely, as you don't include the css-es on the server side. You just insert a HTML reference to them. So as far as the /springway/resources/css/bootstrap-responsive.css URL is what you wanted, and thus @spring.url has worked, it's irrelevant that you have FreeMarker templates here.

Comment: How has "spring.url"  worked ? I still get that error I mentioned on tomcat log.Beside the styles isn't applied yet over my pages !!

Comment: Is there something I missed that bans me to link my freemarker page to the .css !

Comment: FreeMarker is server-side, and loading and applying the css is client-side. In the output HTML, you got a link to "/springway/resources/css/bootstrap-responsive.css", right? It's that URL that doesn't return the CSS, and that's your problem. Thus I said that the problem is not related to FreeMarker.

Comment: @ddekany i was facing the same issue for a spring javamail project while trying to load the css files for freemarker page. In the mail i get `[#import "spring.ftl" as spring /]` with no css applied to the html

Comment: If you literally get `[#import "spring.ftl" as spring /]` in the output (in the final email text) then either FreeMarker is in angle-bracket mode (try *starting* the template with `[#ftl]` to trigger square-bracket mode, or change the `tag_syntax` setting to `"auto_detect"`), or the email wasn't processed by FreeMarker at all (try if `${"something"}` is replaced with `something`).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem it's that spring is trying to respond using the spring servlet but your resources shouldn't be part of it then you need to add the resources path to your Spring configuration. I will add the xml configuration that you should add based on the path where your resources will be

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" cache-period="31556926"/>
```

where

Attribute : location
The resource location from which to serve static content, specified at a Spring Resource pattern. Each 
 location must point to a valid directory. Multiple locations may be specified as a comma-separated list, 
 and the locations will be checked for a given resource in the order specified. For example, a value of "/, 
 classpath:/META-INF/public-web-resources/" will allow resources to be served both from the web app 
 root and from any JAR on the classpath that contains a /META-INF/public-web-resources/ directory, with 
 resources in the web app root taking precedence.

Attribute : mapping
The URL mapping pattern, within the current Servlet context, to use for serving resources from this 
 handler, such as "/resources/**"

Hope this help you